# MySQL CASE statement unrecognized keyword & unexpected token

Tags: mysql

I'm not sure why I have errors on every single word from the first `CASE` keyword and onward in my MySQL query and I'm hoping someone might see something that I've been racking my brain against for the last few hours. Here's a trimmed sample of the code:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE low_revenue_a ENGINE=MEMORY AS
(SELECT fielda,fieldb,
CASE WHEN quality_rev = 'A' THEN 1 WHEN quality_rev = 'B' THEN 2 WHEN quality_rev = 'C' THEN 3 END AS quality_rev,
fieldc,fieldd,
CASE WHEN quality_sales = 'A' THEN 1 WHEN quality_sales = 'B' THEN 2 WHEN quality_sales = 'C' THEN 3 END AS quality_sales,
fielde,fieldf,
CASE WHEN quality_other_sales = 'A' THEN 1 WHEN quality_other_sales = 'B' THEN 2 WHEN quality_other_sales = 'C' THEN 3 END AS quality_other_sales,
fieldg,fieldh,myyear
FROM Db.mytable
WHERE myyear = 2014);
```

Once I added the `CASE` statements, all the Unexpected Token and unrecognized keyword errors show up. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this produce the same error?

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE low_revenue_a ENGINE=MEMORY AS
    SELECT fielda, fieldb,
           (CASE WHEN quality_rev = 'A' THEN 1
                 WHEN quality_rev = 'B' THEN 2 
                 WHEN quality_rev = 'C' THEN 3
            END) AS quality_rev,
           fieldc, fieldd,
           (CASE WHEN quality_sales = 'A' THEN 1
                 WHEN quality_sales = 'B' THEN 2
                 WHEN quality_sales = 'C' THEN 3
            END) AS quality_sales,
           fielde, fieldf,
           (CASE WHEN quality_other_sales = 'A' THEN 1
                 WHEN quality_other_sales = 'B' THEN 2
                 WHEN quality_other_sales = 'C' THEN 3
            END) AS quality_other_sales,
           fieldg, fieldh, myyear
    FROM Db.mytable
    WHERE myyear = 2014;
```

Comment: the issue I had was two fold. one, the brackets did help and eliminated the errors showing up in phpmyadmin. the other reason was my own silly oversight as I misspelled a fieldname: quality_rev. Thanks very much! Regardless, your suggestion did work regarding the plethora of errors I was receiving.